# How to control Flash in IE7

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 is there a way to keep Flash turned off most of the time, but to still have the option to enable it when required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IE7Pro** has this feature

http://www.ie7pro.com

Answer (score 1):

This is only slightly relevant, but [FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433) is one of my must-have add-ons for Firefox.

Flash seems to crash browsers more than anything else - best to keep it in check.

Comment: ...and it helps protecting your privacy. What Flash-enabled sites has your computer visited since you bought it? Look at http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings%5Fmanager06.html to see that list...